# Highcharter hc_add_series_map function : merging regions and displaying labels

Tags: r, highcharts, cartography, r-highcharter

I would like to merge regions in a map and not display intra borders. I also would like to always display the names of the newly grouped regions.
Is hc_add_series_map the right instruction for doing so ?

Thanks in advance for your help

*(I do not use Java for programming, only R)*

Here is an example :

```
mapdata <- get_data_from_map(download_map_data("countries/fr/fr-all-all"))
glimpse(mapdata)

set.seed(1234)
data_fake <- mapdata %>% 
  select(code = `hc-a2`) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1e5 * abs(rt(nrow(.), df = 10)))

glimpse(data_fake)

hcmap("countries/fr/fr-all-all", data = data_fake, value = "value",
      joinBy = c("hc-a2", "code"), name = "Fake data",
      dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format = '{point.code}'),
      borderColor = "#FAFAFA", borderWidth = 0.1,
      tooltip = list(valueDecimals = 2))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxlsy.png)

I would like to add borders for 5 grouped "big" regions, either by deleting 'intra borders' in a region, or adding black lined borders for big regions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, have you check this example http://rpubs.com/jbkunst/highmaps-geojson-simple?

Comment: I just have, it doesn't solve my problem. Actually i have a map with a series and i would like to add borders for grouped regions to appear in the map. I hope it is clear..

Comment: Sorry. Can you show some data and what you have tried?

Comment: I edited the question. thanks

Comment: Each region is a separate shape in `countries/fr/fr-all-all` map, in that case you should create your own map, grouped by regions. However that won't display values per sub-region, only per whole region.